# Error when packaging EXE file using Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, package, inno-setup

I am doing a project on Netbeans and trying to package an exe file and below is the error. I found some related topics to this, but none of them work for me. Can someone help me with this, please?

Thanks.

```
java.io.IOException: Exec failed with code 2 command [[C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6\iscc.exe, /oC:\Users\kenny\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyRebarsProject\dist\bundles, C:\Users\kenny\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler2533082479821554529\images\win-exe.image\MyRebarsProject.iss] in C:\Users\kenny\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler2533082479821554529\images\win-exe.image
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:165)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:138)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:132)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.windows.WinExeBundler.buildEXE(WinExeBundler.java:697)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.windows.WinExeBundler.bundle(WinExeBundler.java:366)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.windows.WinExeBundler.execute(WinExeBundler.java:173)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateNativeBundles(PackagerLib.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateDeploymentPackages(PackagerLib.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask.execute(DeployFXTask.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$75$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:225)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:449)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor192.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:109)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectWrapper.invoke(ReflectWrapper.java:81)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.evaluateScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.executeScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:67)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Script.execute(Script.java:53)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor248.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
C:\Users\kenny\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyRebarsProject\nbproject\build-native.xml:736: Error: Bundler "EXE Installer" (exe) failed to produce a bundle.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed. Actually I had to reinstall Inno Setup 6 and add it to the path again.